# How to prepare custom training data for LayoutLM

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers

I want to train a LayoutLM through huggingface transformer, however I need help in creating the training data for LayoutLM from my pdf documents.

Comment: Do you have anything besides unmarked pdfs such as tokens and boxes from OCR?

Comment: @JohnM thanks , yes I have hocr format for all the pdf files

Comment: That's a good start then. You'll need to transform that content into a very specific format. I have an example at https://www.kaggle.com/jpmiller/layoutlm-starter that may help.

Comment: Hello @AbhishekBisht, did you manage to solve this? any guideline? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @JAD, yeah I have figured out some ways to finetune the lmv2 model on my custom data.

Below are some points for custom dataset creation:

you should have some OCRed data , where you can have bbox co ordinates and respective tokens and respective images 

Then you need to tag your tokens with lables 

I got all the above data from hocr outout, except the tagging, i have use some fuzzy and semiautomatic approach to do the tagging , this is the hard part ,i mean some manual efforts are involved here.

once we have all the above data we can simply use any lmv2 model and fintune it.

Comment: Let me know if you need any other information

Answer (score 0):

Multi page Document Classification can be effectively done by SequenceClassifiers. So here, is a strategy:

1. Convert Your PDF pages into images and make directory for each different category.
2. Iterate through all images and create a csv with image Path and label.
3. Then define your important features and encode the dataset.
4. Save it in your disk.
5. Load it back when you need it using Load_from_disk and dataloader.